# GL_TRIANGLE_ADJACENCY and glDrawElements

Tags: opengl, geometry

So I've not been able to find much online about how data should be stored for triangle adjacency.

Currently I calculate my adjacent using half-edges (mention in an answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62097/building-triangle-adjacency-data)).

But do I store this data in with my VBO? (Which means twice the vertex data)
Or do I store it in my element array buffer? And if so how do I tell opengl the interleaving I would have in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store it in your GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER since the vertex data is just repeated for the adjacency verts.

Assuming that each consecutive 3 indices defines a triangle, and that "`unsigned *ndx`" points to an arbitrary triangle in your buffer, then 6 consecutive indices will define a triangle with adjacency, as follows:

- ndx[0] - index 0 of the original triangle
- ndx[1] - index of the vertex that completes the adjacent triangle for {0,1}
- ndx[2] - index 1 of the original triangle
- ndx[3] - index of the vertex that completes the adjacent triangle for {1,2}
- ndx[4] - index 2 of the original triangle
- ndx[5] - index of the vertex that completes the adjacent triangle for {2,0}